# How can I modify Sitecore Admin to display full name instead of username in the review tab workflow?

Tags: workflow

Sitecore 10

In the Content Tree when I click on an item being edited by another user, in the review tab, I see in the workflow section, "lkjsadf4f" has locked this item.  This is because we are using Okta for Login and the Security Server in Sitecore is assigning a system generated username. So our client can't tell who actually has an item checked out for edit. How can I modify Sitecore to display Full User Name in place of the username which was system generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generation of the username when using identity server is controlled by the `DefaultExternalUserBuilder` class. There are some details about this in the [documentaiton](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/configure-federated-authentication.html), but you can override this to generate more meaningful usernames.

Create a class that inherits from `DefaultExternalUserBuilder` and override the `CreateUniqueUserName()` method:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Identity;
using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services;
using Sitecore.SecurityModel.Cryptography;

namespace MyProject.IdentityProvider
{
    public class ExternalUserBuilder : DefaultExternalUserBuilder
    {
        public ExternalUserBuilder(ApplicationUserFactory applicationUserFactory, IHashEncryption hashEncryption) : base(applicationUserFactory, hashEncryption)
        {
        }

        protected override string CreateUniqueUserName(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ExternalLoginInfo externalLoginInfo)
        {
            string hashDerivedName = base.CreateUniqueUserName(userManager, externalLoginInfo);
            string domain = hashDerivedName.Substring(0, hashDerivedName.IndexOf('\\'));
            string providerKeyName = domain + @"\" + externalLoginInfo.Login.ProviderKey;

            // Check name not already assigned. 
            return userManager.FindByName(providerKeyName) == null ? providerKeyName : hashDerivedName;
        }
    }
}
```

Modify the line that sets the `providerKeyName` with the correct values based on the values your ptovider returns.

You can then patch this on your CM server with the following config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set">
  <sitecore>
    <federatedAuthentication>

      <identityProvidersPerSites>
        <mapEntry name="all sites">
          <externalUserBuilder set:type="MyProject.IdentityProvider.ExternalUserBuilder, MyProject.IdentityProvider" resolve="true">
            <IsPersistentUser>true</IsPersistentUser>
          </externalUserBuilder>
        </mapEntry>
      </identityProvidersPerSites>

    </federatedAuthentication>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```